# GNU make directory listing using $(shell dir ) command

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to list all the subdirectories inside a certain folder. My operating system is Windows 10, I am using a GNU Make file and the version is : GNU Make 4.0 Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin, and this is the command I used :

```
ROOT_DIRECTORY := X:\

DIRS := $(shell dir $(ROOT_DIRECTORY) /s /b /ad)

$(info subdirs : $(DIRS))
```

when I execute the command `dir /s /b /ad` using the **CMD** it works just fine however when I try to execute it using the $(shell ) function the output is :

```
./tools/bin/sh: dir: command not found
subdirs :
```

Answer (score 0):

`make` does not use `cmd.exe` to run shell commands, at least not by default.  It uses a POSIX shell, which you can see is the component that issues your diagnostic message (`.tools/bin/sh`).  The shell command for listing directory contents is [`ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), but it will not, by itself, give you what you want, because it has no equivalent to `dir /ad`.

That you are attempting to do this at all is suspicious.  If `make` is an appropriate tool for your job at all then you should probably be approaching the problem in a different way.  If you must use `make`, however, then one option would be to ensure that Cygwin's `find` program is installed, and use that:

```
DIRS := $(shell find * -type d)
```

(Be sure not to get Windows's `find` command, which does a different job.  You may need to provide a path to the correct `find`.)

Another option might be to run `cmd.exe` explicitly.